# How would I display a For and Reverse For Loop on the same Line C#

Tags: c#

I have been trying to get both a For and Reverse For loop to display on a line in this formation `Number x Number`

Due to the number being an input `(people % i==0)` is there to find factors of the number that has been given.

```
                for (int i = 2; i <= people - 1; i++)
                {   
                    if (people % i==0)
                    {
                        Console.Write($"{i}m x ");
                        //Console.WriteLine($"{i} is factors of {input}");
                           

                    }
                }


                for (int j = people - 1; j >= 2; j-- )
                {
                    if (people % j == 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"{j}m");
                        
                    }
                    
                }
```

Comment: What is the `%` maths in there for? Can you explain more clearly what you're asking? Reading [ask] may help.

Comment: `foreach (var entries in people.Zip(people.Reverse(), (first, second) => new { first, second})` may be an option to consider.

Comment: @Enigmativity The ```%``` is to find factors of the given number as it is input (Will edit the question to have this)

Comment: @Console.Writeline - Are you trying to compute a list of factors? If you are, just do this: `$"{i} x {people / i}"`.

Comment: @Enigmativity Unfortunately ``` $"{i} x {people / i}" ``` Causes the "Newline in Constant" and ) Expected errors (Used on both If and Console.Writeline)

Comment: @Console.Writeline - No, it doesn't. You mustn't have entered it in correctedly.

Comment: @Enigmativity could you show me how you made it work

Comment: @Console.Writeline - It was just `Console.Write($"{i} x {people / i}");`.

Answer (score 3):

C# [for](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/for) can use compound assignments/expressions (zero or more statements separated by commas)

```
int people = 10;

for (int i = 2, j = people - 1; i <= people - 1; i++, j--)
   Console.WriteLine($"i = {i}, j = {j}");
```

**Output**

```
i = 2, j = 9
i = 3, j = 8
i = 4, j = 7
i = 5, j = 6
i = 6, j = 5
i = 7, j = 4
i = 8, j = 3
i = 9, j = 2
```

***Note** : this is very common in C/++ however it's less common in C#; we tend to like things declarative, neat and readable.*

---

Or you can calculate it on the fly

```
int people = 10;
for (int i = 2; i <= people - 1; i++)
    Console.WriteLine($"i = {i}, j = {people-i+1}");
```

[**Full Demo Here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ljDuZb)

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in a way to achieve this using `Linq`, this is achievable using a `Zip` operation:

```
int start = 2;
int people = 9;

Enumerable.Range(start, people - start + 1)
    .Zip(Enumerable.Range(start, people - start + 1).Reverse(), (x, y) => $"{x}m x {y}m")
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

**Output**

```
2m x 9m
3m x 8m
4m x 7m
5m x 6m
6m x 5m
7m x 4m
8m x 3m
9m x 2m
```

Answer (score -1):

Create another index `j` in the first for loop

```cs
for (int i = 2; i <= people - 1; i++)
{   
    if (people % i==0)
    {
        Console.Write($"{i}m x ");
        //Console.WriteLine($"{i} is factors of {input}");
    }
    
    int j = people - i + 1;
    if (people % j == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{j}m");
        
    }
}
```